# Javascript - Replace all non-alpha numeric characters except period

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all non alpha-numeric characters in a file name except for the period, I've been searching around and found close answers but not exact, here is what I narrowed it down to:

```
var temp = originalname.replace(/\W+/g, "_");
```

But this replaces everything, how can I exclude the period here (or any other characters if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
var temp = originalname.replace(/[^\w.]+/g, "_");
```

`[^\w.]+` will match 1 or more of any character that is not a word character and not a DOT.